# Unable to create or delete Excel service application due to timeout

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services, service-application, distributedcache

On my server Excel Calculation Service is "started".

I tried to create new Excel Service Application but after some time I get following error.

[image]

And this is how it looks like after that.

[image]

If I try to delete, it takes even longer time (probably a few hours) and then show same request time out message.

From logs, I found two entries but none give any clue as to what the issue is.

> System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.

AND

> SPTimerJobAsyncResult '9e0cc344-ae13-47f8-8b43-a0535e885651': An error
>   occurred while waiting for completion:
>   System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
>       at System.Threading.Thread.SleepInternal(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
>       at System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPJobDefinition.WaitForCompletion(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobAsyncResult.WaitForCompletion(Object
>   state)

Could this be happening because Distributed Cache service is also not running on server and I tried to fix it but no luck?

Comment: are you tried to remove it via powershell $spapp = Get-SPServiceApplication -Name "Excel Service"
Remove-SPServiceApplication $spapp

Comment: also try to restart SharePoint Timer Service

Comment: Yes I have tried Powershell but no luck. Then I had to use stsadm to delete the service application. Restart timer service along with IIS several times. Also did server restart.

Comment: Do you face the same issue for all application services or just Excel?

Comment: Other application services are created and running but I am not sure if I am using any of them apart from may be UPS and Managed Meta Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I noticed that Excel Service Application that I created yesterday has magically started working. I am not sure how it happened and the only thing I remember is that I disabled anti virus on server and tried creating it again yesterday.